# SSL Client Authentication Issue between WebSphere and GlassFish servers

Tags: ssl, websphere

I have an issue connecting to a GlassFish server (external party) from WebSphere (our server) when using SSL Mutual Authentication.

It looks like the SSL negotiation has succeeded but then one side or the other requests a renegotiation I think and the other side does not respond.

In my WebSphere logs I see the following:

```
[14/06/13 12:33:00:904 EST] 00000026 SystemOut     O MAC:  update
[14/06/13 12:33:00:904 EST] 00000026 SystemOut     O Proxy : 3, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
[14/06/13 12:33:00:904 EST] 00000026 SystemOut     O MAC:  update
[14/06/13 12:33:00:904 EST] 00000026 SystemOut     O Proxy : 3, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 2740
[14/06/13 12:33:01:435 EST] 00000026 SystemOut     O Proxy : 3, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 20
[14/06/13 12:33:01:435 EST] 00000026 SystemOut     O MAC:  update
[14/06/13 12:33:01:435 EST] 00000026 SystemOut     O Proxy : 3, RENEGOTIATE 
[14/06/13 12:33:01:435 EST] 00000026 SystemOut     O JsseJCE:  Using MessageDigest MD5 from provider IBMJCE version 1.2
[14/06/13 12:33:01:435 EST] 00000026 SystemOut     O JsseJCE:  Using MessageDigest SHA from provider IBMJCE version 1.2
[14/06/13 12:33:31:447 EST] 00000028 SystemOut     O Proxy : 5, called closeOutbound()
```

Everything prior to this looks like normal SSL TLSv1 comms.

I installed my own GlassFish server and created a test application which I can connect to fine from WebSphere so I assume I am missing some configuration option that is set by the external party.

I think the renegotiation comes from the GlassFish server but I am not certain.

Any GlassFish or WebSphere experts who might have an idea?